# How can I control the order of processing items in/from get-childitem -recurse

Tags: powershell

Trying to educate myself: when processing a whole tree of items from

`get-childitem -recurse`

I often have to do it from the leaf level up to the top level (for example, deleting files and folders, it's problemmatic to modify the upper levels of the tree and then attempt to deal with the lower levels.

To work around this, I've resorted to sorting the whole collection by the number of delimiters in the paths, to get the leaf level first, followed by upper levels of the tree:

`$someFiles = Get-ChildItem -Recurse |
  Sort @{Expression={ ( $_.fullname | select-string "\\" -AllMatches ).matches.count };
  Descending=$true }`

This feels wrong - I have limited coding experience, but I know that if I just traverse the tree in the right way, this expensive and goofy sort should not be necessary. But -recurse is so handy!

What's the smarter way to do this? To be specific, is there a way to traverse the tree with get-childitem, from leaf up, that does not require sorting all the results?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could avoid the regular expression and just use the string split method. It also performs better.

```
dir -recurse | sort -Property @{ Expression = {$_.FullName.Split('\').Count} } -Desc
```

Result:

```
TotalMilliseconds : 346.1253
```

vs...

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Sort @{Expression={ ( $_.fullname | select-string "\\" -AllMatches ).matches.count }; Descending=$true }
```

Result:

```
TotalMilliseconds : 953.6606
```

Comment: That speeds things along, and mjolinor is also correct that just the length of the path should work (children might be shorter than others, but cannot be shorter than their parents). I just wanted to eliminate the whole sort thing altogether by feeding the collection in the right order, using a better tree traversal method. Academic, I guess, but I'm curious :-)

Answer (score 4):

I just use  the length of the fullname:

```
gci -recurse | sort @{expression = {$_.fullname.length}} -descending
```

All child items will get sorted before their parent container.

Comment: I think the OP is trying to sort by folder depth rather than path length.

Comment: OK. But if you're deleting an entire folder tree and just need to be sure you don't try to delete a parent before all it's child items are deleted, it will accomplish the same thing.

Comment: I don't quite understand that part because obviously all children will be deleted when the parent is deleted so what does it matter? However based on the current example, it's by folder depth so `C:\ShortName\A\B` will be in the array before `C:\A really really long folder name`

Comment: Depending on what you're using to do the delete, it may fuss if there's childitems still in the folder.  As far as "C:\A really really long folder name" being in the list before "C:\ShortName\A\B", if you're deleting them all that won't matter, as long as all the child items of either folder are in the list before that folder.

Comment: Yeah, the main issue is that if you remove a parent folder first (or change it) then later in the loop it'll throw an error trying to access something that no longer exists.